# Constructing a sequence with a pattern in R

Tags: r

I'd like to construct a sequence with length 5000 of the following type: `x<-c(1:i,(2*i):(i+1),(2*i+1):(3*i),(4*i):(3*i+1),...)`, with `i=2,3,4....,2500`.
I'm thinking about building this sequence as the sum of two sequences: the first is `a=1:5000` while the second is going to be a sequence containing the pattern. For example, when i=2 I have the following: `c(0, 0, 1, -1)`, whereas for i=4 I have `c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, -1, -3)`. When i=2, I can construct a vector like `b=c(rep(0,i),i-1,i-3)` and then add up `a` and `b` to get the result I want (thanks to the recycling rule).

I'm trying to find a way to "generalize" the second part of the vector (namely, the part without `rep()`), maybe subtracting to `i` a sequence from 1 to 5000 moving up by 2. However, I should stop the vector after the pattern I want  to repeat many times (e.g., after 4 components in the case i=2). Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: very unclear. What is a?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Take `i=2`. Your sequence becomes `1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, ...` Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the question very unclear. If the request is for a series of vectors of increasing length where the first n values are zero and the next n values are n-1 to -(n-1), then this is one possibility:

```
 lapply(1:10 ,   #obviously this is a toy demonstration
        function(n)  c(rep(0,n), seq(n-1, 1-n, length=n) ) )
 #-----------
     [[1]]
[1] 0 0

[[2]]
[1]  0  0  1 -1

[[3]]
[1]  0  0  0  2  0 -2

[[4]]
[1]  0  0  0  0  3  1 -1 -3

[[5]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  4  2  0 -2 -4
Snipped remaining output.
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Sorry for being so unclear.

Comment: Hah! The cognitive encoder transfer apparatus works again. Will get to work in a patent right away.